# Como adicionar valores na JTextField através do botão sem apagar o valor anterior?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

O meu problema é que eu coloquei um botão para que quando fosse clicado, adicionasse o valor `1` na `JTextField`.

Porém, quando eu clico de novo, ele substitui o valor, e o que eu queria é que ele adicionasse mais outro `1` tipo, eu clico uma vez dai la na textfield ia ficar `1`, dai eu clico de novo e ia fica `11`, dai eu clico novamente e ficaria `111` e assim por diante. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta fazer um tratamento dentro do `actionPerformed` do seu botão, capturando o valor atual do campo e incrementando `1`(string, não inteiro), sempre checando o status atual(se já possui dados ou está nulo/vazio) antes de incrementar, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
String textoAnterior = seuTextField.getText();


if(textoAnterior == null || textoAnterior.isEmpty()){
    seuTextField.setText("1");
} else {
    seuTextField.setText(textoAnterior + "1");
}
```

Veja este trecho funcionando no exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTextFieldTest {

    public void start(){
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField(15);
        JButton botao = new JButton("Concatenar");

        botao.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                String textoAnterior = tf.getText();
                //verifica se o campo está vazio ou nulo para evitar
                // exceções por incremento a valores nulos ou perda
                //dos dados já digitados
                if(textoAnterior == null || textoAnterior.isEmpty()){
                    tf.setText("1");
                } else {
                    tf.setText(textoAnterior + "1");
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(tf);
        panel.add(botao);


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(250, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        tf.requestFocus();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JTextFieldTest().start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Vlw cara, ajudo muito.

Comment: @PauloAleixo se a resposta lhe ajudou, você marca-la como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda dela, assim, servirá de referencia para outros usuarios. :)